# PHP cURL methods time out on some URLs, but command line always works

Tags: php, curl

When I attempt to use PHP's cURL methods for SOME URLs, it times out.  When I use the commandline for the same URL, it works just fine.

I am using AWS and have a t2.medium box running the php-55 apache libraries from yum.

Here is my PHP code:

```
function curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept-Language: en-us'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
$fh = fopen('/home/ec2-user/curllog', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fh);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fh);
$headers = explode("\n",$a);
var_dump($headers);
var_dump($a);
exit;

        return $result;
}
```

So here is call that works just fine:

```
curl('http://www.google.com');
```

And this returns the data for the homepage of google.

However, I try another URL:

```
curl('http://www.trulia.com/profile/agent-1391347/overview');
```

And I get this in the curllog:

```
[ec2-user@central Node]$ cat ../curllog
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.0.160.99...
* Connected to www.trulia.com (23.0.160.99) port 80 (#0)
> GET /profile/agent-1391347/overview HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
Host: www.trulia.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us

* Operation timed out after 10002 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
```

If I run this from the command line:

```
curl -s www.trulia.com/profile/agent-1391347/overview
```

It IMMEDIATELY returns (within 1 second) with NO output. This is expected.  However when I run this:

```
curl -sL www.trulia.com/profile/agent-1391347/overview
```

It returns the page properly, just as I would want.

So, what is wrong with my curl?

PHP 5.5.20

Here is the cURL bit from my phpinfo():

```
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.38.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version => NSS/3.16.2 Basic ECC
ZLib Version => 1.2.7
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.2
```

Comment: Are you running the command line from the same machine as the php code? if not you may want to compare the curl version.

Comment: what's the output of terminal `curl --version` ? and what's the output of `<?php var_dump(curl_version());` ?

Comment: IRC snippet: https://i.imgur.com/bOwxcS3.png - ... and the guy that answered, is the author of (lib-)curl

Comment: @hanshenrik `< curl --version
curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.51.0 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.6.2 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.4.2 ...SNIP...

php > var_dump(curl_version());
array(9) {
  ["version_number"]=>
  int(471808)
  ["age"]=>
  int(3)
  ["features"]=>
  int(2000797)
  ["ssl_version_number"]=>
  int(0)
  ["version"]=>
  string(6) "7.51.0"
  ["host"]=>
  string(23) "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"
  ["ssl_version"]=>
  string(10) "NSS/3.28.4"
  ["libz_version"]=>
  string(5) "1.2.8"
  ["protocols"]=>
  array(22) {
    SNIP
  }
}`

Comment: @ShawnTolidano that is php-cli. is php-cli where you have the problem? or do you experience the problem in an apache mod_php? or in a php-fcgi?  if its the latter, does your php-cli and your php-whatever have the same version?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: The script is working for me... Maybe it has something to do with the network settings?

Comment: Information overflow in the question, too much code for the problem, you should better reduce that. Also I can't reproduce. Works like a charm. Curl on the commandline perhaps uses a proxy while within the webserver environment this is not the case?

Comment: The second URL is using Cloudfront. Your PHP is using curl 7.38, your command line is using curl 7.51. You're not the first to have this bug (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603641/strange-timeout-with-php-curl-and-ssl) and they fixed by upgrading the version of Curl in PHP - so I'd try that. Also, PHP 5.5 is not longer supported (except security updates) so might be time to take the plunge and upgrade to 5.6 or, if code can handle 7?)

Answer (score 9):

I have checked your function `curl()` It seems fine. No need to change anything in the function. What should you need to do is just pass the URL as it is as parameter no need to change `HTTPS` to `HTTP`

`curl('http://www.trulia.com/profile/agent-1391347/overview');`

Reason:

You already told `curl` to don't verify the `SSL`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Let me know if you need any explanation.

Comment: Ah, nothing like turning security off! :-)

Answer (score 5):

The verbose output shows a clear timeout problem:

> - Operation timed out after 10002 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

This signals a problem with your network setup. These are harder to locate, this can be on your own end (e.g. in context of the webserver or the PHP executable) or on the other end. Both places are possible to a certain extend, however the server accepts both requests even if they have different request headers, so it is more likely that this is execution context related which is also how you generally describe it.

Check if there are any restrictions on security and other networking layers regarding performing those requests via PHP. E.g. try a different server image if you're not so into system administration and trouble-shooting. From what is shared in your question, this is hard to say what exactly causes your timeout.

Answer (score 4):

Try increasing the timeout values in the following lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

Those are pretty short timeout values - the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT specifically limits the entire execution time, try giving larger values:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
```

Comment: It runs instantaneously from the command line - under 1 second. I should not need 10 seconds in PHP to do what takes 1 on the CLI. I did try it with double values though and it still times out. I ran on a different EC2 instance and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 VARIABLES

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

The first one, `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` is maximum amount of time allowed to make connection to the server`

You can disable it by setting it to `0`.

That is

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
```

But it is not a good method if you are in a production environment because it will never timeout.

Now `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`

From [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

Set it to some higher value

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); // 20 Seconds.
```

Comment: My particular problem, and why I put the bounty on it, isn't answered by the timeouts.  Look at the first statement in the post -- the issue is that it times out only *sometimes* when called from PHP, but *never* when called from the command line -- even when used on the same URL both times.

Comment: I measure from my pc, it takes 10+ seconds with curl command, most of the time used on data transfer. So it means we triggered the cdn's speed limit(by cloudfront.net for this example). You should figure out how to bypass the speed limit, or just set a larger CURLOPT_TIMEOUT